# if statements, a faster way?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement, coding-style

I know this can be faster but i dont have years of experience in coding so i am just learning the hard way..

I made a function that checks if a string is not "" if not add it to a nsurl and then i check if the nsurl is not nil and add it to a mutable array:

```
-(void)CheckUrls
{    
self.items = [NSMutableArray array];


NSURL *URL1 ;
NSURL *URL2 ;
NSURL *URL3 ;
NSURL *URL4 ;
NSURL *URL5 ;
NSURL *URL6 ;


NSLog(@" FOTO 1: %@ \n FOTO2 : %@ \n FOTO 3 : %@ \n FOTO 4 : %@ \n FOTO 5: %@ \n FOTO 6: %@ \n",self.searchResult.foto1,self.searchResult.foto2,self.searchResult.foto3,self.searchResult.foto4,self.searchResult.foto5,self.searchResult.foto6);

if (![self.searchResult.foto1 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto1];

}
if (![self.searchResult.foto2 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    URL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto2];

}
if (![self.searchResult.foto3 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    URL3 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto3];

}
if (![self.searchResult.foto4 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    URL4 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto4];

}
if (![self.searchResult.foto5 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    URL5 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto5];

}
if (![self.searchResult.foto6 isEqualToString:@""]) {
    URL6 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto6];

}



if (URL1 !=NULL) {
    [items addObject:URL1];
}

if (URL2 !=NULL) {
    [items addObject:URL2];
}
if (URL3 !=NULL) {
    [items addObject:URL3];
}
if (URL4 !=NULL) {
    [items addObject:URL4];
}
if (URL5 !=NULL) {
    [items addObject:URL5];
}
if (URL6 !=NULL) {
    [items addObject:URL6];
}
```

Can this function be optimized ?

Comment: If blocks are some of the fastest constructs. Really, doing it a different way would only lead to readability/less code, rather than performance.

Comment: go for `array` with a `for` loop.

Comment: use self.searchResult.foto1.length == 0 instead of isEqualToString:@""

Comment: Are you asking if this could be optimzed in the least amount of code needed or optimized in terms of speed?

Comment: You could combined the 2 sets of if statements

Comment: @ShiftyThomas Speed.... its readable enough..

Comment: Unless you've benchmarked this and seen that it's a performance bottleneck, you should be focus on making the code easier to maintain. The current form is quite brittle and inflexible... opting for using arrays & loops would make the code far shorter and much easier to maintain/modify in the future (i.e. adding support for a 7th photo would be trivial and not error-prone like it is now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray* photosToCheck = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  self.searchResult.foto1, self.searchResult.foto2, self.searchResult.foto3, self.searchResult.foto4, self.searchResult.foto5, self.searchResult.foto6, nil];

for (NSString* photo in photosToCheck) {
    if (photo.length > 0) {
        NSURL* photoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:photo];
        [items addObject:photoUrl];
    }
}
```

However, having properties named `foto1`, `foto2`, ... immediately tells us that an array should be used to hold data instead.

Comment: This is much nicer code, but slightly slower (not that that is very important).

Comment: @trojanfoe If I went for performance, I would use plain C :) However, this code is probably what he needs although he claims different.

Comment: It's how I would write it and I wouldn't worry about the performance at all.

Comment: @Sulthan so for speed optimization its good enough but for readable code and future proof its better to do it like this. it also saves on the making of vars like url1,url2 etc... tnx !

Answer (score 0):

if you have exactly 6 fotos, leave it as it is.
Otherwise use an array of Urls, and loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing against an empty string is equivalent to testing if the string has zero-length.  It won't save much in terms of CPU time, but is at least easier to read.  Also you can store the URL in the array when you set them, so there is no need to test them later:

```
if ([self.searchResult.foto1 length] > 0) {
    URL1 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto1];
    [items addObject:URL1];
}
if ([self.searchResult.foto2 length] > 0) {
    URL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto2];
    [items addObject:URL2];
}
// etc.
```

And if you don't actually use `URL1` etc you can just put them straight into the array:

```
if ([self.searchResult.foto1 length] > 0) {
    [items addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:self.searchResult.foto1]];
}
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make self.searchResults a NSArray of Strings that you fill wherever you give values to the foto's

There are 2 ways to do for loops either

```
for(NSInteger x = 0;x<100;x++)
```

which will loop until the condition is false in this case x is greater than 99 or

```
for(NSObject *key in anArrayOfObjects)
```

which will loop through each object in the array

Null checking is always a good idea, the (NSString *) is typecasting the [NSNull null] to be a null NSString

```
url != (NSString *)[NSNull null]
```

You don't need the intermediate NSURL since you will already know if the foto value is empty or null so you can immediately put the object as a new NSURL into the array of items

```
[items addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Final code

```
-(void)CheckUrls
{    
    self.items = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(NSString *url in self.searchResult){
        if( url != (NSString *)[NSNull null] && ![url isEqualToString:@""] ){
            [items addObject:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since sending a message to a `nil` object returns `nil`, a single check of `url.length > 0` will return false if `url` is nil or empty, and true if it has at least one character (which would require it to be non-nil). Code can be made a bit simpler and more streamlined if you leverage that aspect of nil objects.

Comment: zubergram i cant make an array of self.searchResult because its a costum class with other data as well

Comment: add an NSArray to the custom class then